# Is it true that cruise lines are not allowed to sell alcohol and certain foods whilst in Israeli waters?

Tags: food-and-drink, israel, cruising, alcohol, mediterranean

All being well regards to the current epidemic I shall be embarking on a cruise this November 24th which includes a two day stop in Israel.
Obviously as a middle aged male the all inclusive drinks package will be one of the highlights of the cruise over that of the free water flumes.
However, I have been informed by an unofficial source that whilst in Israeli waters the cruise line will not be allowed to sell alcohol, and certain foods will also be banned until back out of Israeli waters.
This could mean two or three days without alcohol which makes an all inclusive drinks package less beneficial, so thus I may pass up on the all inclusive drinks package and simply pay as I go, unless of course it is not true that they will be required to stop serving alcohol.

So do cruise lines traveling to Israel need to stop serving alcohol whilst in Israeli waters?

Comment: Are 2 or 3 days without alcohol really that bad?

Comment: @Rg7x gW6a cQ3g When on holiday is the only time one consumes alcohol, astounding yes.

Comment: @Rg7xgW6acQ3g Is the answer to your question in any way relevant for the topic which is asked about here?

Comment: Did you ask this to the cruise agency/organisation?

Comment: If the prohibition is solely on _sales_, you could, as they say, 'line them up'...

Comment: @Aak Not yet. During Covid it can take a while to get through, as they are under staffed just now, and in truth i have many months yet before the issue becomes something of emergency.

Comment: I’ve heard of quite a few restrictions regarding alcohol sales and/or consumption in Muslim states, especially the more hardline countries such as Saudi Arabia, which have an impact on operations on flights for instance, but I’ve never heard anything like that about Israel (as far as I know, Judaism doesn’t prohibit alcohol consumption, does it?). There are sometimes tax/customs related rules but a ship at sea shouldn’t have an issue with that. Does the ship make multiple stops in Israel?

Comment: @Rg7xgW6acQ3g John's question isn't implying they won't take the trip if there are days on which alcohol won't be served. They are evaluating a decision as to the cost/benefit of buying a package where drinks are all-included, vs staying with a package where they pay for each drink when ordered. For such a decision, it's reasonable to estimate that individual's "normal" spend on a per-day basis for drinks when paying as they go, then see if the all-inclusive price is lower than that * # of possible days, or if the all-inclusive package would allow them to do more of something they enjoy.

Comment: Might the prohibition of alcohol in Israeli waters be in place to encourage people to buy drinks on the mainland, much like some Cinemas prohibit bringing your own snacks when you go see a movie? Just a thought.. I've nothing to back this up..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. And there shouldn't be any reason for it.

Alcohol is sold freely in Israel without any serious prohibition except for the usual underage and licensing rules. This includes an Israeli [cruise line company](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mano_Maritime) that operates from Israel and sells alcohol at all times, including in the territorial waters of Israel.

All food is generally allowed to be sold, including specifically non-kosher food. There are some rules regarding food that is not kosher for Pesah during the holiday, but it wouldn't apply to a cruise ship, and it only regulates its display, not its sale or consumption.

There might be issues with very specific individual items that are regulated, as are the quirks of every country and its food and safety regulations (like with kinder surprise eggs being illegal in the US) but not something broad that should affect the food in a major way and for sure not prohibit the sale of alcohol entirely.

Comment: Serving of alcohol has been restricted or even completely prohibited in several European countries during the last year as part of covid lockdown restrictions. Are you sure that is not the case for Israel?

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Ctrl-F "alcohol" [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COVID-19_pandemic_in_Israel) shows no results so it wasn't restricted.

Comment: @JonathanReez The Covid pages on Wikipedia are at best incomplete and many of them plain wrong on many topics. The Wikipedia page on Covid 19 in Norway does also not mention any restrictions on sale of alcohol, but there are restrictions in place right now and these restrictions at least apply to ferries going to/from Norwegian ports.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo, there were no restrictions on the sell and consumption of alcohol due to the covid lockdown. Some places that sell alcohol, like bars, restaurants and others were closed due to them being places where people gather. And I'm not sure if liquor store were essential enough to be allowed to stay open, but there was no restriction on the sale of alcohol in places that were allowed to stay open like supermarkets or in delivery or other non-mass gathering ways. Also, just recently restaurants and bars were opened for people who have been vaccinated.